# How does static maintain its value over function call

Tags: c, static

Recently in one of the interview, I came across this question " How does static variable maintain its previous value across function call".  Thought for a while but really couldn't think any convincing answers. Can anybody please explain this? Tried doing Google, couldn't find my info.

Comment: How does a global variable maintain its value?

Answer (score 5):

Static variables are stored in the .data area where all the global variables are stored. And these global and static variables are allocated as part of the exec operation(i.e creating a new process/ forking a new process).

```
         -----------------------
         | Command Line Arg    |
         |---------------------|
         |     Stack           |
         |      \/             | < Grow downward
         |---------------------|
         |      /\             |
         |     Heap            | < Grows Upward
         |---------------------|
         |     .bss            | (Uninitialized global variables)
         |---------------------|
         |     .data           | (initialized global/static variables)
         |---------------------| 
         |     .text           |
         -----------------------
```

In the above figure .data is the area where all the static variables which are declared inside the function or declared as global variables are stored. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

In simple terms, a static variable inside a function is similar to a global variable. The compiler makes all the necessary checks regarding visibility and access to the variable. Beyond that, it's just another global var.

Thus, it's legal to do this:

```
int *test_static()
{
    static int func_var = 1234;
    printf("%d", func_var);

    return &func_var; // return pointer to int
}

int main()
{
    int *i = test_static(); // will print '1234' and point i to func_var

    // we can't do "func_var = 99;" here, but...

    *i = 99;
    test_static(); // will print '99'

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not suggesting that we *should* practice this though! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Static variables (inside a function or not) are in the global memory space.  They are initialized at program start and reside for the length of the program.

---

C11 5.1.2 "All objects with static storage duration shall be initialized (set to their
initial values) before program startup."

6.2.4.3 "...  Its lifetime is the entire execution of the program and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup."

Answer (score 1):

Think of function scoped static variables as global variables only visible to the scope of the function they're defined in.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the ISO C standard, section 6.2.4 paragraph 2:

> The *lifetime* of an object is the portion of program execution during
>   which storage is guaranteed to be reserved for it. An object exists,
>   has a constant address, and retains its last-stored value throughout
>   its lifetime.

Paragraph 3:

> An object whose identifier is declared ***[SNIP]*** with the storage-class
>   specifier **static**, has static storage duration. Its lifetime is the
>   entire execution of the program and its stored value is initialized
>   only once, prior to program startup.

That explains why it's *required* to maintain its previous value, but not *how* it does so (it's not the standard's job to tell implementations how to do things, just what they must do).

*How* does it do so? In any way the implementation chooses to make it do so. You could as easily ask why it wouldn't maintain its previous value.

But basically it's stored in some region of memory that's allocated just before your `main` function starts, and that's not deallocated as long as the program is running, and whose contents are not modified unless the program itself does so.

In this respect, there's no difference between an object defined at file scope vs. an object defined inside a function with the `static` keyword; both objects have static storage duration, and are likely to be stored in the same region of memory.

Answer (score 0):

A static variable exists throughout the lifetime of the program being executed. It does not cease to exist when the thread of execution leaves the function in which it's declared. So, it never loses its value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving you a reference which may help you suppose.

[Description on 'static keyword'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable)